# Does PAC4J-SAML support multiple IDPs discovery

Tags: pac4j

I'm using pac4j-saml 6.0.1 and I need to support multiple IDPs. Is there a support for that?
I know there is a standard for IDPs discovery: https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/Post2.0/sstc-saml-idp-discovery.pdf

I tried looking at SAML2Configuration API but couldn't find anything that looks relevant.

Answer (score 0):

No, IdPs discovery is not available in pac4j. You can "only" define multiple `SAML2Client`, i.e. multiple IdPs.